# Simple query combining counting statements in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm constructing a data set based on sources from the late seventeenth and eighteenth centuries, detailing the relations between laypeople and various churches in the Dutch Republic. I would like to create a simple query that counts the number of baptisms and marriages that occurred in a particular church and period. I used this data to play around with:

```
CREATE (em0002: event: marriage { day: 16, month: 6, year: 1650, LOCAL_ID: 'em0002'})
CREATE (em0003: event: marriage { day: 16, month: 6, year: 1670, LOCAL_ID: 'em0003'})
CREATE (eb0001: event: baptism { day: 16, month: 6, year: 1665, LOCAL_ID: 'eb0001'})
CREATE (c0001: church: RCC { name: 'Kerk aan de Appelmarkt', location: 'Leiden', LOCAL_ID: 'c0001'})
CREATE (c0003: church: DRC { name: 'Gereformeerde Kerk', location: 'Leiden', LOCAL_ID: 'c0003'})
CREATE (em0001)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(c0001)
CREATE (em0003)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(c0001)
CREATE (eb0001)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(c0001)
CREATE (em0002)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(c0003)
```

It is fairly easy to retrieve the number of baptisms in a particular period, which can be done by this query:

```
WHERE e.year > 1650 AND e.year < 1680
RETURN count (e:baptism) AS Number_of_baptisms
```

The problem is when I want to create an overview with the number of baptisms in one column and the number of marriages in the other.

I simply don't know how to link the two queries (one counting the marriages and the other the baptisms. This one doesn't give the right result:

```
WHERE e.year_trouw > 1650 AND e.year_trouw < 1680 
MATCH (ee:baptism)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(ch:church:RCC {name: 'Kerk aan de Appelmarkt'})
WHERE ee.year > 1650 AND ee.year < 1680
RETURN count (e:marriage) AS Number_of_marriages, count (ee:baptism) AS Number_of_baptisms
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Tailor according to your logic

```
MATCH (e1:baptism), (e2:marriage)
WITH {baptism:COUNT(DISTINCT e1), marriage:COUNT(DISTINCT e2)} AS col
RETURN col.baptism AS Baptism, col.marriage AS Marriage
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, in that it counts all the events and makes a distinction between baptisms and marriages, but it doesn't take into account the year parameter (i.e. the period in which these events occurred).

Comment: Hi, just add your filter parameters after the MATCH line - I left that for you to tailor :)

Answer (score 0):

This query uses the [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function:

```
MATCH (event:event)
WHERE 1650 < event.year < 1680
RETURN REDUCE(s={b:0, m:0}, e IN COLLECT(event) |
  CASE WHEN e:baptism THEN {b:s.b+1, m:s.m} ELSE {b:s.b, m:s.m+1} END
) AS counts
```

to produce the baptism/marriage counts:

```
╒═════════════╕
│"counts"     │
╞═════════════╡
│{"b":1,"m":1}│
└─────────────┘
```

*The query, as written, assumes that any `event` that is not a `baptism` is a `marriage`.*

*BTW: An expression like `count(e:baptism)` does more work the way you intended. `e:baptism` evaluates the `e` node to see if it has the `baptism` label and returns a boolean value. So, you are actually counting the total number of trues and falses (i.e., the total number of `e` nodes). Instead, `count(e)` would give you the same count and is more efficient.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. I'll have to study the query carefully, this is rather above my proficiency! Thanks, also, for the explanation of the count function.